# Django get_total_topup() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Tags: django, python-3.x

```
class IndexAjaxView(View):
   def get(self, request): 
      param = request.GET.get('param')

      if param == 'get_total_topup':
        return self.get_total_topup()

      return JSONResponse({}, status=404)

   def get_total_topup(self, request):
      return JSONResponse({
        'value': 'Rp.{:,.0f},-'.format(
            TopUp.objects.filter(owned_by=request.user).aggregate(Sum('amount'))['amount__sum']
       )
      })
```

somebody can help me ? I want to get data via ajax, but the response is 500 with message get_total_topup() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call in `return self.get_total_topup()` has no arguments but your definition `def get_total_topup(self, request)` requires one. Try `return self.get_total_topup(request)`.

```
class IndexAjaxView(View):
   def get(self, request): 
      param = request.GET.get('param')

      if param == 'get_total_topup':
        return self.get_total_topup(request) # <--- just change this

      return JSONResponse({}, status=404)

   def get_total_topup(self, request):
      return JSONResponse({
        'value': 'Rp.{:,.0f},-'.format(
            TopUp.objects.filter(owned_by=request.user).aggregate(Sum('amount'))['amount__sum']
       )
      })
```

Comment: do you mean to be like this ?                                                                                     def get_total_topup(self, request):
        return JSONResponse({
            'value': 'Rp.{:,.0f},-'.format(
                TopUp.objects.filter(owned_by=request.user).aggregate(Sum('amount'))['amount__sum']
            )
        })

        return self.get_total_topup(request)

Comment: Much simpler than that. I've updated the answer to show what I mean.  "request" won't be filled in by Django because you are calling it from inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one positional argument in the method call.

```
return self.get_total_topup()
```

Fix it to

```
return self.get_total_topup(request)
```